# Eigenvalues of second kind Fredholm integral operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, integral-equations

Let $K\in L^2((0,1)\times(0,1))$ and consider the operator defined in $L^2(0,1)$ by
$$Lu(x):=u(x)-\int_0^1K(s,x)u(s)ds.$$
What kind of assumption might I impose on $K$ such that $\lambda=1$ will be not an eigenvalue of the operator $L$?. Any ideas?. Thank you.

Comment: Well if $Tu(x)=\int_0^1 K(s,x)u(s)ds$, then you would have to demand that $\ker(T)=\{0\}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If this always satisfied if the kernel K has a constant sign ?

Comment: Are you asking if $K$ not changing sign implies $\ker(T)=\{0\}$? I think that this not true, just by taking $K\cong 1$. In that case the function $\sin(2\pi x)$ is an eigenfunction with eigenvalue $0$. Or atleast I think so.

Comment: Thank you sir, I see now. Thank you again.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Do you see any assumption on the kernel to ensure that the kernel of  $T$ is reduced to zero?.